# Something is wrong with my scaling

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

Following a tutorial like my recent questions,
link to that down the bottom.

I have come across another problem, this one being when I scale some bones that aren't attached they move instead of going towards the centre.

What it should look like:

[image: What it should look like]

What it looks like:

[image: What it looks like]

Now, all of the bones are selected that need to be, and the size thing has gone to the centre and when I press "." and hold it, it shows 3D cursor, which is what I want. I hope I've shown what is wrong here.

Tutorial link:
https://youtu.be/ktXD_WRMY8E?t=1984

at 33:06

File:
[image]

[image: See this]

Comment: It's hard to understand when you talk about a `size thing` ;) I advise you to upload your file on [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here, so we can have a look.

Comment: There we go, i have added the file

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue: https://i.imgur.com/Dzq2tCr.gif

Comment: Now to be fair, there are some known bugs with the current Blender version that cause some issues with bone selection, and might make things like this a bit unpredictable when the bug occurs. Maybe try to, while in pose mode, deselect everything by clicking in an empty area of the viewport, then select the bones again by just holding shift and clicking them one by one. Then try scaling again.

Comment: Still does it! I'll give you my process, 1. In Object, mode go to the hierarchy/outline and select the armatures in the armature collection. 2. Switch to pose mode. 3. Shift-Click the very end bones, they should be small ones. 4. Ctrl + S to scale. then it gives me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjqpu.png

Comment: Should be S to scale. After step 3, you should see your armature objects selected in the outliner (in addition to the bones you selected inside each of them). If not, shift click one of the bones you selected (except the last one).

Comment: Sorry yes just S, my bad :) I see the image at the very bottom of my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139475/discussion-between-jerry-and-l0lock).